# R, dplyr - combination of group_by() and arrange() does not produce expected result?

Tags: r, dplyr

when using dplyr function `group_by()` and immediately afterwards `arrange()`, I would expect to get an output where data frame is ordered *within* groups that I stated in `group_by()`. My reading of documentation is that this combination should produce such a result, however when I tried it this is not what I get, and googling did not indicate that other people ran into the same issue. Am I wrong in expecting this result?

Here is an example, using the R built-in dataset ToothGrowth:

```
library(dplyr)
ToothGrowth %>%
  group_by(supp) %>%
  arrange(len)
```

Running this will produce a data frame where the whole data frame is ordered according to `len` and not within `supp` factors.

This is the code that produces the desired output:

```
ToothGrowth %>%
  group_by(supp) %>%
  do( data.frame(with(data=., .[order(len),] )) )
```

Comment: Can you file a bug report please?

Comment: Can you please link to this bug report?

Comment: @Paul4forest The [issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/491) is closed, so either it is already in the current release or it is still in the development branch.

Comment: @Hrvoje thanks for the link. According to Hadley's test case, `arrange()` sorts first by columns in the `group_by()` function and then by those in the `arrange()` function.                                    test_that("grouped arrange sorts first by group", {
  df1 <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(disp) %>% ungroup()
  df2 <- mtcars %>% arrange(cyl, disp)

  expect_equal(df1, df2)
})

Comment: @PaulRougieux, I don't fully understand your reply. `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(disp) %>% ungroup()` produces the same undesired result as `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(disp)` It is not the same as `arrange(cyl,disp)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you want

```
ToothGrowth %>%
  arrange(supp,len)
```

The chaining system just replaces nested commands, so first you are grouping, then ordering that grouped result, which breaks the original ordering.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although it fixes my particular problem, I think it would not work in more general cases where you might want to preserve the ordering of original `supp` variable.

Comment: then make supp a factor and specify the ordering using levels

Comment: I want to do exactly this, why can't it just work the way you think it should (i.e. group by first, then arrange)

Comment: I prefer it this way because it is more explicitly following directions. Before you would ask it to sort a variable and it would be insubordinate until you added an `ungroup()` that could snip away all the snags keeping the arrange from working as requested.

Answer (score 98):

You can produce the expected behaviour by setting `.by_group = TRUE` in `arrange`:

```
library(dplyr)
ToothGrowth %>%
    group_by(supp) %>%
    arrange(len, .by_group = TRUE)
```

Comment: FWIW this is the answer I was looking for given the stated question.

Comment: that helped me too !

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881405/how-to-sort-groups-within-sorted-groups) question especially needs an answer like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to fix this unexpected order issue while still using the `group_by()` statement is to convert the `grouped_df` back to a `data frame`.
group_by is needed for summaries for example:

```
ToothGrowthMeanLen <-  ToothGrowth %>%
    group_by(supp, dose) %>%
    summarise(meanlen = mean(len))
```

This summary table is not arranged in the order of meanlen

```
ToothGrowthMeanLen %>%
    arrange(meanlen)
```

This summary table is arranged in the order of meanlen

```
ToothGrowthMeanLen %>%
    data.frame() %>%   # Convert to a simple data frame
    arrange(meanlen)
```

Converting `grouped_df` back to a data frame is the first way I found to sort a summarised data.frame. But in fact `dplyr::ungroup` exists for that purpose.

```
ToothGrowthMeanLen %>%
    ungroup() %>%   # Remove grouping
    arrange(meanlen)
```

Comment: @antoine-sac actually you can use ungroup() which is nicer.