# How to arrange nested data (i.e., data with parenting) in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset with multiple levels:

1. Categories (e.g., "Countries")
2. Countries (e.g., "USA")
3. Cities (e.g., "New York")
4. Counties (e.g., "Manhattan")
5. Places (e.g., "Times Square")

Each row (except for LVL 1 entries) is linked to a parent a level above.

For example: Times Square->Manhatten->New York->USA->Countries

**My question:** how to sort this dataset:

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(3,6,9,11,12,19,411,50,77,83,105),
                      Parent = c(12,12,77,105,19,NA,3,41,19,77,19),
                      Level = c(3,3,3,3,2,1,4,5,2,3,2),
                      Name = c("New York","Boston","Oxford","Vancouver","USA","Countries",
                               "Manhattan","Times Square","UK","London","Canada")),
                 class = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

into this:

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(19,12,3,41,50,6,77,83,9,105,11),
                      Parent = c(NA,19,12,3,41,12,19,77,77,19,105),
                      Level = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,3,2,3),
                      Name = c("Countries","USA","New York","Manhattan","Times Square",
                               "Boston","UK","London","Oxford","Canada","Vancouver")),
                 class = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

In `df2`, the list is arranged according to the level first, but each linked sub-level is directly underneath.

I have tried several `dyplr::arrange()` variants (e.g., `arrange(Level, Parent)`) but all fail to account for the nested data. I think the solution might be a combination of group_by() and using arrange( ,.by_group = TRUE) as done here ([R, dplyr - combination of group_by() and arrange() does not produce expected result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649730/r-dplyr-combination-of-group-by-and-arrange-does-not-produce-expected-res)). Unfortunately, I couldn't solve it by myself.

Can anyone help? A `tidyverse`/`dplyr` solution would be preferred :-)

Comment: Have you considered using a nested list for your data? I find it easier to manage structured data/data with varying levels. Just a thought. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `igraph::dfs`

```r
library(igraph)

g <- with(na.omit(df2), graph.data.frame(cbind(Parent, ID), directed = TRUE))
 

data.frame(ID = as.integer(names(dfs(g, root = "19")$order))) |>
  left_join(df2)
           
##> + Joining, by = "ID"
##>     ID Parent Level         Name
##> 1   19     NA     1    Countries
##> 2   12     19     2          USA
##> 3    3     12     3     New York
##> 4   41      3     4    Manhattan
##> 5   50     41     5 Times Square
##> 6    6     12     3       Boston
##> 7   77     19     2           UK
##> 8    9     77     3       Oxford
##> 9   83     77     3       London
##> 10 105     19     2       Canada
##> 11  11    105     3    Vancouver
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stefano! When copying your code, R is complaining about an unexpected token (">"). Is there a typo in your code or am I missing something?

Comment: @diggi2395 No, it's not a typo. `|>` is the new pipe operator in R-4.1. You can safely substitute with `%>%`.

Comment: Ahh, I see! Unfortunately, I got another error as the object "out" in left_join() couldn't be found?

Comment: @diggi2395 eheh that was a typo. It should be fixed now!

Comment: Perfect, now it worked! Thanks again :-)